# closed javafx window handler

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have to write a method that will do something when the user closes a window. So far I managed to write this code but it does not work (i placed it in my initialize method in my controller) :

```
 Scene scene = myTable.getScene();


     Window window = null;
        if (scene != null) 
        {
        window = scene.getWindow();
        System.out.println("scene is not null");
        window.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>    
        ()
        {

        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent w)
        { 
            System.out.println("do somethong here");

        };
        });
```

Unfortunately Even my message "scene is not null does not get displayed. Does anyone have a better idea on how to do it?

Comment: *"Unfortunately Even my message "scene is not null does not get displayed."* Doesn't get displayed because it's obvious that scene is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something when the user closes the window you should use the setOnCloseRequest() method like this :

```
window.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

        @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Now if scene is `null` then this code won't be executed and nothing will happen, maybe a little `System.out.println(scene);` before the test would help you debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add a change listener to the scene property of the table, and only add your event handler when the scene is changed to a non-null value.

As recommended by Marc, calling [setOnCloseRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnCloseRequest%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) or [setOnHidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnHidden%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29), is probably a better way to configure your EventHandler.